# Is there a way to see a preview of images on a folder thumbnail in the finder?

Tags: nautilus

Ubuntu 20.04

Is it possible to see an example image incorporated as part of the folder thumbnail in the finder?

[image]

I have a lot of folders with random ids, and each contain a specific group of images within. Right now, when I'm browsing I need to click into each to see the image thumbnails, but I'd love to see it on the folder thumbnail instead so I can scroll an visually browse.